# Portable programming - Linking fails fails with Win32 but links with linux

Tags: c++, winapi, linker, portability, mingw32

I am working on a portable application which is running under Linux and Windows. 
I am cross compiling on a linux system using cmake, gcc 4.4.4 and mingw-gcc 4.4.4.

I can compile and link the Linux version of my application without problems. However if I try to cross-compile for Windows, the application compiles fine, but the linker ends with an 'undefined reference' error.

Here is the excerpt from the source code:

Header File (fileactions.hpp):

```
class FileActions {
    bool CopyFile(const std::string &source, const std::string &destination);
    bool CopyFile(const boost::filesystem::path& source, const boost::filesystem::path& destination);
};
```

Source file (fileactions.cpp):

```
bool FileActions::CopyFile(const boost::filesystem::path& source, const boost::filesystem::path& destination)
{
    return this->CopyFile(source.string(), destination.string());
}

bool FileActions::CopyFile(const std::string &source, const std::string &destination)
{
    /* ... do something */
}
```

Excerpt from code which causes the link-error:

```
bool TmmProject::PostImportOldVersion(int old_version) {
    namespace fs = boost::filesystem;
    FileActions dd;

    fs::path backup;
    /* fs::path _location; // This is actually defined in the class declaration */

    /* do something more */

    if( !dd.CopyFile(_location, backup ) ) {  <-- I get the linker error at this line
        log << "<span style=\"color:red\">Failed to create backup file. Stopping import </span><br>";
        log << "The error message is: " << dd.GetError() << "<br>";
        _last_error = log.str();
        return false;
    }

    /* do something more */
}
```

As said, above code links fine if I compile for linux system, but fails if I use mingw to compile for Win32. The exact linker error is:

```
CMakeFiles/tmm.dir/tmmproject.cpp.obj:/.../tmm/tmmproject.cpp:408: undefined reference
to 'tmm::fileActions::CopyFileA(
   boost::filesystem::basic_path<std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, boost::filesystem::path_traits> const &, 
   boost::filesystem::basic_path<std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, boost::filesystem::path_traits> const &
)'
```

The file fileactions.cpp is linked into a static libray libtmm. The TmmProject class, which causes the error, is part of the the same library.

The CMakeLists.txt which is used to link the library looks like this (shortened):

```
include_directories( ... )
link_directories ( ${Boost_LIBRARY_DIRS} )

file(GLOB TMM_HEADERS *.h)
file(GLOB TMM_SOURCES *.cpp)

set ( TMM_LIBS 
  ${Boost_LIBRARIES}
  ${PYTHON_LIBRARIES}
  m
)

IF( WIN32 )
    ADD_LIBRARY( tmm STATIC ${TMM_SOURCES} )
    target_link_libraries( tmm ${TMM_LIBS} )
    # I found the following option from a similar quesiton in this froum, but
    # actually it does not seem to make any difference
    SET_TARGET_PROPERTIES( tmm PROPERTIES LINK_FLAGS -Wl,--export-all-symbols )
ELSE( WIN32 )
    ADD_LIBRARY( tmm SHARED ${TMM_SOURCES} )
    target_link_libraries( tmm ${TMM_LIBS} )
    INSTALL(TARGETS tmm DESTINATION lib)
ENDIF( WIN32 )
```

Has anyone an Idea what could be the reason for the failure?

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft is using a lot of defines in their header for unicode support. In your case the name `OpenFile` seems also to be defined to be eiter `OpenFileA` or if you switch to unicode it would be `OpenFileW`.
To get rid of this problem add this after including the headers from microsoft.

```
#undef CopyFile
```

You can of course pack it into a `#ifdef` to limit it to the microsoft platform.

Comment: Thank you for your quick answer. As I wrote in the comment to the other answer, this was the cause for the problem. Using #undef did not work for me, but renaming my library functions solved the issue.

Answer (score 1):

This is Microsoft using macros to allow applications to use "UNICODE" (wide or 16-bit character) and "ASCII" (8-bit character) forms of the ssystem calls. So somewhere in Windows.h there is something like:

```
#if UNICODE
#define CopyFile CopyFileW
#else
#define CopyFile CopyFileA
#endif
```

Whilst using `#undef CopyFile` (and similar) will work, I would suggest that you avoid including `<windows.h>` unless ABSOLUTELY necessary - if you have to, try to limit that to a small number (ideally one) source file that actually directly interacts with Widnows.

Comment: Thank you very much for your quick answer! This was actually the problem. Unfortunately, "windows.h" was not included by myself, but by some libaray header I was using. So my final solution was to rename the methods FileActions::CopyFile to something else.